# Compilation error while running code with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm new to RxJava so forgive me all my newbie mistakes ;)

I have following code:

```
Observable
            .fromIterable( observables )
            .flatMap(task -> task.observeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
            // wait for all tasks to finish
            .lastOrError()
            .flattenAsObservable( x -> someWeirdMapWithObject.values())
            .cast(BrandBuilder.class)
            .map( brandBuilder -> brandBuilder.build() )
```

`observables` is a list of Observables which will write data to `someWeirdMapWithObject`. As name suggest someWeirdMapWithObject has `Object` as values.

Strange thing is that in Intellij IDEA this snippet will do fine, no errors, no warnings (except one - brandBuilder.build() can be inlined).
But when I try to compile this code, it gets compilation error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
                .map( brandBuilder -> brandBuilder.build() )
                                                  ^
  symbol:   method build()
  location: variable brandBuilder of type Object
```

When I change last line to:

```
.map( brandBuilder -> ((BrandBuilder) brandBuilder).build() )
```

it's all good.

My questions are:

- why does cast operator don't work?
- is my code proper? Is there any way to execute it better?
- and why (to quote Tommy Wiseau: 'Why, Java why?') this code doesn't compile?

Thanks in advance for response ;)

**EDIT**

Better example below (as Junit Test, I've noticed that when I make observables of same type this code will compile otherwise it won't):

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Observable<String> first = Observable.fromCallable(() -> "HEY").delay(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    Observable<Integer> second = Observable.fromCallable(() -> 1).delay(350, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    List<Observable> observables = com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(first, second);
    Map<Long, Object> someWeirdMapWithObject = com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(
            1L, new BrandBuilder(1),
            2L, new BrandBuilder(2)
    );
    Observable
            .fromIterable(observables)
            .flatMap(task -> task.observeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
            // wait for all tasks to finish
            .lastOrError()
            .flattenAsObservable(x -> someWeirdMapWithObject.values())
            .cast(BrandBuilder.class)
            .map(BrandBuilder::build)
            .toList().blockingGet();
}

class BrandBuilder{
    private int bar;
    BrandBuilder(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    public Brand build(){
        return new Brand(this.bar);
    }
}

class Brand{
    private int bar;
    Brand(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be a type inference anomaly that either your Javac version or IntelliJ version is wrong about. What versions are you using?

Comment: I'm using Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2017.1.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: What is your java version? Also please provide a standalone example that contains all objects and type definitions.

Comment: Can you show your brandBuilder.build() implementation ??

Comment: @akarnokd implementation added, openjdk version "1.8.0_151"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the raw type in this declaration:

```
List<Observable> observables =
    com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(first, second);
```

This seems to throw off javac in the flow below and prevent generics/inference from working properly. Use

```
List<Observable<?>> observables =
   com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(first, second);
```

instead and everything below should compile.

For me, Eclipse latest did indicate problems in the editor, highlighting the `::build` part so I guess IntelliJ not reporting the error could be a bug there.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thnak you :)